# Moving javascript from user control into appropriate master page

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, user-controls, master-pages

I have a scenario like this (simplified for this question):

I have a master page:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Ads.master.cs" Inherits="ActiveDigitalSignage.Ads" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <form id="form1" runat="server">
                <header>
                </header>
                <section>
                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
                    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                </section>
            </form>
        </div>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="script" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have a default.aspx page:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Ads.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <div><p>Test</p></div>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="script" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
```

The way its setup is, any header stuff can go in the "head" section. The main stuff goes in the "ContentPlaceHolder" and any javascript goes into the "script" place holder. Everything is working fine as is right now.

The issue I'm running into is I want to use a User Control (.ascx) in my Default.aspx page. However there is javascript in the user control. Because the jQuery is at the bottom of the page (in the "script" section), the javascript in the user user control is breaking. Is there a way to make the javascript in the user control render inside the "script" placeholder?

I know I can just copy and paste the code into a .js file and load the javascript in my master page. The problem with doing that is there are a bunch of ASP.NET tags (e.g. <%= %>) in the javascript that reference controls in the user controls, so copying and pasting this into a .js file would break this.

I'm thinking, off the top of my head, there might be a way in the global.asax page, during prerender, that can detect javascript in a user control and dynamically move it into the proper section?